# Facebook cocoapods 'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdk

I have installed the facebook sdk via cocoapods but I get the below error:

> 'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App
>   Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate
>   instead.

relating to line 701 in FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.m

> UIViewController *vc = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController;

Why is this happening and how do I resolve it?
podfile:

```html
   # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your 
 project
 # platform :ios, '9.0'

 target 'testapp' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic 

frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for testapp

pod 'FLAnimatedImage', '~> 1.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
pod 'FacebookCore'

 pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.5.2', '< 3.0'


  target 'testappTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.5.2', '< 3.0'
end

  target 'testappUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try  to comment `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` target & pod , clean , install and run again

Comment: Hi, I replaced those dependencies, cleaned and tried to build but still get the same error.

Comment: try to comment OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension target & pod , clean , install and run again

Comment: Hi, I have removed One Signal from my project and that has resolved the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 49):

You can add the following block to your `Podfile` to address this programatically.

If you are using pods you can add the following block to your `Podfile` to address this issue:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'No'
    end
  end
end
```

This will set the `require only App-Extension-Safe Api` to `No` for all pod project targets and should allow your builds to succeed.

Answer (score 23):

That's what helped me:
**Pods** project -> select **Target** which contains this error -> **Build Settings** -> set **Require Only App-Extension-Safe API** to **No**

You might probably have to do the same for other FB frameworks

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem,i solved it by
setting `require only App-Extension-Safe Api` to `no`
it seemed that all the facebook pods `require only App-Extension-Safe Api` were set to yes so i have to set no for all `xcodeproject,target,all facebook pods` ,
you can find `require only App-Extension-Safe Api in build setting for pods,target,and project` **important note when ever you reinstall pods they are reseted to yes**

Answer (score 1):

**For the ones who need `oneSignal` in their project:**

The problem is the place the `oneSignal` pods are added in the `podfile`. I had the below code in my `podfile`:

```
target 'my_app_name' do
  pods()

  target 'my_app_name_dev' do
    pods()
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    # require for m1 mac
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  end

  target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
    pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0', '< 4.0'
  end
end
```

The reason the project was failing to run was I had added the `oneSignal` lines inside the main project target (`my_app_name` target) while `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` is a separate target in the project, so I moved it out of my app target pods and it worked:

```
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0', '< 4.0'
end

target 'my_app_name' do
  pods()

  target 'my_app_name_dev' do
    pods()
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    # require for m1 mac
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  end
  
end
```

Comment: Had exactly the same problem, with RNScreens yelling at me for some reason, but I just implemented Onesignal and this solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have already tried other approaches and none of them working and if you are getting this error in your main project and not in your app extension then just make your method unavailable for app extension.

```
@available(iOSApplicationExtension, unavailable)
    static var getTopSafeArea: CGFloat {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) {
            return window.safeAreaInsets.top
        }
        return 0
    }
```